# iPad IMAP client

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, email

Can anyone suggest an IMAP client for my iPad2 that can be password protected.

I want to be able to check my work email on the iPad but at the same time I don't want my daughter accidentally mucking about with my emails.

<sub>FYI:

The web-access I have to my e-mail is truly horrendous so please don't suggest I use that</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply removing the password from the email setup should help.

Comment: Seems like the best option to me!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the App Store won't allow other IMAP clients as a matter of policy (you're not allowed to duplicate functionality present in native apps), so unless you jailbreak you're not going to find a 3rd party client on the App Store.

The simplest solution to your problem would be to just passcode-protect the iPad so your daughter can't access it.

One alternative (if you don't like your existing webmail) might be to use a 3rd-party webmail client that lets you just check your IMAP email using a web interface. Sadly, Gmail will only do this for POP3, but after a quick Google, it appears some of the links on [this page](http://emailaddresspro.com/check-pop3-imap-email-via-the-web/) may be useful for that purpose (though I can't vouch for any of them in particular). Mail2Web and MyEmail seem to be the least-obviously-bad choices there.

Anyway, that would add a layer of security between your daughter and your email, effectively substituting for the 3rd party client application you're looking for.

Comment: Not entirely true. If that's the case we won't have any third party calculator apps. Sparrow announced that they're working on an iOS IMAP client (not sure if it's password protected).

Comment: @Enrico Hmm... I know that most of the high-profile rejections from the App Store have been things that duplicate functionality. A cursory examination of 3rd-party email clients all seem to offer a specific additional feature they're marketed on that makes it okay for the store. In any case, the passcode lock or 3rd party webmail is still the best option. User restrictions don't allow for restricting the whole Mail app, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm aware of that too, but I think if you have an app that has a functionality that is not in the Apple's apps then that wouldn't be classified as duplicating functionality. I guess that's why we see third party browsers as well. Check this interview, they think Apple will approve them: http://www.businessinsider.com/dom-leca-interview-sparrow-2011-8

Answer (score 0):

Have the iPad lock itself with a numeric password?

Comment: Won't work. My daughter uses it as much (or more) than I do.